# Baccarat Probability

Tags: probability, combinations, gambling

What is the probability of the player winning with each score from 0-9 in the first hand/play? There are 416 cards (8 decks) and each score is the sum of the 2 cards drawn e.g. 2 and 4 = 6. All cards are face value except 10, J, Q, K which are all 0 and Ace = 1. 
There is a player and a banker, whoever gets a higher total wins. If either hand gets a natural - 8 or 9, they automatically win except if one hand is 9 and the other is an 8, so the 9 wins. There are ties in the game. If the total goes above 9 e.g. 15, you subtract 10 from the score - 17 - 10 = 7. Here are the rules for both the player and the Banker.

*Player*
Gains a 3rd card if the total of their initial hand is between 0-5. If their total is 6 or 7, the player stands (doesn't draw). Banker follows same rules if remains at two cards.

*Banker*

1. If the player draws a 2 or 3 as a third card, the banker draws a third card if their total is 0-4, but stands (doesn't draw a card) if they have a total between 5 -7.
2. If player draws a 4 or 5, the banker draws a third card if their total is between 0-5, but if not, the banker stands if their total is 6 or 7.
3. If player draws a 6 or 7, the banker draws a card if their total is between 0-6. If it isn't and their total is 7, they stand.
4. If an 8 is drawn by the player, the banker draws a third card if their total is 0-2, but they don't draw a card if their total is between 3-7.
5. If 9 or a 0 is drawn (10,J,Q,K), banker draws a third card if their total is 0-3, but the banker stands if their total is between 4-7.

Comment: That page doesn't specify how many decks are used. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccarat_(card_game)) says that $6$ to $8$ decks are used. Please provide a full specification of the problem here in the question; the link may go dead at some point and thus reduce the long-term value of any answers provided to your question.

Comment: There are 8 decks in the game and the first hand is drawn. So the first play and there are rules for both player and banker. Player draws third card if the total is between 0-5.
For Banker - If player draws a 2 or 3 as thrid card, banker draws third if total is 0-4 but stands with 5 -7. If player draws 4 or 5, banker draws third if total is 0-5, but stands with 6 or 7. If player draws 6 or 7, banker draws is total is 0-6 but stands at 7. If 8 is drawn, banker draws third card is total is 0-2 but stands at 3-7. If 9 or a 0 is drawn (10,J,Q,K), banker draws is total is 0-3 but stands at 4-7.

Comment: Please update the question accordingly; it should be self-contained and not rely on the comments to be understood; the comments may not all be shown later on when more comments are added.

Comment: I didn't find any of those rules in your last comment under the link you provided. Please explain the jargon involved ("stand"), and try to form grammatically correct unambivalent sentences (e.g. "banker draws is total is $0-6$ but stands at $7$" is unclear). You are much more likely to get an answer if the problem is clearly stated and can be understood without undue effort.

Comment: stand mean doesn't draw. Doesn't take a third card. And ill shall fix my wording. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!